# Is there an Excel function for flipping the sign?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there an Excel arithmetic function that flips a sign? Such a function would be used in lieu of the `zero minus` in the following...

```
=IF(G5<0,ROUND(0-G5,2),"")
```

Comment: Why can't you remove the 0 as in ROUND(-G5,2)?

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/732543/how-do-you-reverse-the-sign-of-a-range-of-numbers-in-excel/732544

Comment: or use ABS(): `=IF(G5<0,ROUND(ABS(G5),2),"")`

Comment: @ScottCraner, ABS is good in the context of this particular formula but ABS does not always flip the sign.

Comment: @H2ONaCl I was answer this specific question, I realize that it does not flip the sign.  but your if precludes any positive numbers and as such it will do what you want in this specific case.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Zero increases visibility. A function would also increase visibility.

Comment: if you want visibility you can always must multiply by `-1`: `-1*G5`. Because there is a simple mathematical method to flip the sign, there is no need for a function.

Answer (score 1):

The formula **=-A1** would give you the negated value of cell A1.